# Mysql procedure, recurrently return hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have user table, which has following fields

user 
    user_id INT
    parent_user_id INT
    a INT
    b INT

I want to create procedure which returns all child nodes for given parent_user_id

Here what I have

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS read_user_tree;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE read_user_tree(IN input_data INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    SET @id = input_data;
    myLoop: loop
        SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b` into @id, @a, @b FROM `user` WHERE parent_user_id = @id;
        if  
            @id is null
        then
            leave myLoop; 
        end if;
           SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b` FROM `user` WHERE user_id = @a
           union
           SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b` FROM `user` WHERE user_id = @b;

    end loop myLoop; 

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this PROCEDURE, I am getting random results not the tree data

Edit 1:

I try to add data into temp table but getting error "#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row"

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS read_user_tree;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE read_user_tree(IN input_data INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    SET @id = input_data;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_user_data (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `a` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `b` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `parent_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  myLoop: loop
        SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b` into @id, @a, @b FROM `user` WHERE parent_user_id = @id;
        if
            @id is null
        then
            leave myLoop;
        end if;
        insert into tmp_user_data (`user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id`)
        SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id` FROM `user` WHERE user_id = @a;
        insert into tmp_user_data (`user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id`)
        SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id` FROM `user` WHERE user_id = @b;

    end loop myLoop; 

    select * from tmp_user_data;

END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT 2:

After adding second tmp table to use as queue I get desire result

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS read_user_tree;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE read_user_tree(IN input_data INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    SET @id = input_data;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_user_data (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `a` int(11) , 
    `b` int(11) , 
    `parent_user_id` int(11)
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_user_level (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


  insert into tmp_user_level select user_id from `user` WHERE parent_user_id = @id;
  myLoop: loop
        select user_id into @cur from tmp_user_level LIMIT 1;
        select FOUND_ROWS() into @cnt;
        if
            @cnt = 0
        then
            leave myLoop;
        end if;
        SELECT `user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id` into @user_id, @a, @b, @parent_user_id FROM `user` WHERE user_id = @cur; 
        insert into tmp_user_data (`user_id`, `a`, `b`, `parent_user_id`) values( @user_id, @a, @b, @parent_user_id);
        delete from tmp_user_level where user_id = @cur;
         if
           @a is not null
        then
            insert into tmp_user_level (user_id) values(@a);
        end if;

        if
           @b is not null
        then
            insert into tmp_user_level (user_id) values(@b);
        end if;

    end loop myLoop; 
    select * from tmp_user_data;


END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Going from memory, so apologies if wrong. But you might need to create a temporary table and insert the results of the queries while inside the loop. That's how I used to do it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results LIKE `user`;
...
<loop>
...
INSERT INTO results (user, a, b)
   SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ;
...
</loop>
SELECT * FROM results;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE results;
```

You have to have the permission to create temporary tables;

Comment: how will this work if multiple users call procedure the same time?

Comment: TEMPORARY TABLE is handled internally by Mysql and gets an actual random filename and is deleted once the stored procedure is finished. It's designed to run with multiple users with no cross polination

Comment: I tried still does not work for me  getting - #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: I changed to have two tmp tables looks like working fine